creating a user repository for fedora and equivalent using existing rpms and publishing it online
i need help and i would thank and appreciate anyone who may provide it.
i found that rocky/alma/centos stream do not have xen in their repos.
i thought of making my own repo as a user repo and put xen and the missing packages into it so people can use it to install xen if they needed to.
for such thing i looked for a way to do it, i mostly wanted to download the rpm packages and upload them to the repo that i made.
i felt like such thing is not possible, if possible someone tells me how though.
otherwise all i found is fedora's method to make a copr repo using tito, i assumed i need the source code which will create some files needed later for the build till the full installation
i believe there is something missing and wrong about understanding fedora's copr approcach from me
please tell me what to do, if you need any further details you can ask me anything in order to get them. thank you
i thought of downloading xen alongside the dependencies from fedora then make a git repo in github then follow the steps in fedora's copr guide using tito but i believe i did not understand it the way it should be

You can use the Copr build system to build the package, and it will host the repository for you. See https://docs.pagure.org/copr.copr/user_documentation.html#quick-start
